# SFSpeechRecognitionRequest on Xamarin.iOS requiresOnDeviceRecognition. Is it available?

Tags: xamarin.ios, offline, transcription, sfspeechrecognizer

I am using this article which also has a sample for Speech recognition in **Xamarin.iOS** using Apple's  **SFSpeechRecognition**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/speech?tabs=macos

The sample works fine but it doesn't work without internet. There is an option in iOS 13 and above of a boolean value **requiresOnDeviceRecognition** which if set to true, it will do **offline transcription** according to their documentation.

The problem is that, i am not seeing this option anywhere in the Xamarin.iOS documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/3152603-requiresondevicerecognition?language=objc

Can someone please guide me to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property in the documentation, but if you write the code such property is available:

```
        var request = new SFSpeechUrlRecognitionRequest(new NSUrl("path", false));
        request.RequiresOnDeviceRecognition = true;
```

Comment: THANKS. It even works with the buffer request without Pre-recording: 
   recognitionRequest = new SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest {
    ShouldReportPartialResults = true, RequiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
   };

Comment: For those who might be confused if it fails on the simulator, it needs to run on an actual physical device if you use offline transcription.